# Listen for element prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I have elements that are dynamically prepended to an area on my site, but I need something to listen for when they are prepended, so it can fire an event.

The elements are prepended like so

```
something.prependTo('#area')
```

The element that is being prepended is like this

```
<div id="box1" class="box new">
```

I have tried each of the following with no luck...

```
$('.new').on(playSound());
$('.new').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', playSound());
$('.new').each(playSound());
$('.new').live(playSound());
$('.new').livequery(playSound());
```

The sound plays when the page initially loads, but not when an element is prepended.

Comment: What's wrong with putting the `playSound()` code the line after the `prependTo` call?

Comment: What causes the prepend to happen? Why can't you trigger an event there? livequery should have worked, if you use `playSound` rather than `playSound()` and included the livequery plugin.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after `playSound`!!! You want to *bind* the function, not call it.

Comment: `$('#area').on('DOMNodeInserted', playSound);`

Comment: @adeneo Is there a way to check the class of the DOM node that's inserted? I only need to fire the playSound event for certain classes.  Archer, It's actually not my site, so I don't have the ability to edit the code. I'm just working on a plugin for it.

Comment: Sure it is, but that's a bit much to add in a comment, so I'll have to add it is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#area').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {//whenever an element is inserted
    if ($(e.target).is('.new')) {             //check if it has the right class
        playSound();                          //and play sound
    }
});
```

It won't work in IE as there is no support, and if I remember correctly mutation events are deprecated, so there's no guarantee for future support either ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
function prependWithSound(something){
    something.prependTo('#area')
    playSound();
}
```

And then call  `prependWithSound(something)` instead of   `something.prependTo('#area')`.

Why make life harder then it should be?

Answer (score 1):

[LiveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) will do it, but as @Bergi pointed out, you have to remove the parens:

```
$('.new').livequery(playSound);
```

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LH9TA/)